# react-dnd getDecoratedComponentInstance() is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-dom, react-dnd

I am currently building a feature for file upload and sorting within react.

I have used the following examples:

- https://gaearon.github.io/react-dnd/examples-chessboard-tutorial-app.html
- https://github.com/okonet/react-dropzone
- https://github.com/gaearon/react-dnd-html5-backend

Everything worked fine, until it came to eslint telling me not to use findDOMNode within js/componenets/File.jsx in my repository below.

https://github.com/GregHolmes/react-dnd-dropzone

It happens when I try to re-sort the position of the images. Ie drag 2nd image to 1st place.

After a search, I found an example over how to resolve this. However that example just wont work. This example was: [React DnD: Avoid using findDOMNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40499267/react-dnd-avoid-using-finddomnode#)

As with their example I tried the following:

js/components/File.jsx:35

`<div ref={node => this.node = node} style={{ ...style, opacity }}>`

Then in the same file I uncomment line 62:

`const rawComponent = component.getDecoratedComponentInstance();`

and replace (line 71):

`const hoverBoundingRect = findDOMNode(component).getBoundingClientRect();`

with (line 70):

`const hoverBoundingRect = rawComponent.node.getBoundingClientRect();`

I then get:

`getDecoratedComponentInstance() is not a function`

Does anyone have any idea how I might go about resolving this issue? I apologise for the mess in my code. I am new to react and have been attempting to keep things as clean as possible.

**Edit**

I thought I'd resolved the problem with the below. However doing this meant that I couldn't drag the images to the other box. Switching around the let exportFile = DragSource..... with DropTarget, gave me my initial issue of the function call not being a function.

At the bottom of my File.jsx file. I had:

```
export default flow(
DropTarget("FILE", fileTarget, connect => ({
    connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget()
})),
DragSource("FILE", fileSource, (connect, monitor) => ({
    connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
    isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
}))
)(File);
```

I replaced this with:

```
function collectDragSource(connect, monitor) {
    return {
        connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
        isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
    };
}

function collectDropTarget(connect) {
    return {
        connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget()
    };
}

let exportFile = DragSource('file', fileSource, collectDragSource)(File);
exportFile = DropTarget('file', fileTarget, collectDropTarget)(exportFile);

export default exportFile;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need to create a `rawComponent` variable and call `getDecoratedComponentInstance` which doesn't exist as a method on the component anyway.

The `node` can simply be access on the `component` instance via the `node` property which mean you can simply do

```
const hoverBoundingRect = component.node.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Btw you also seem to have the dependencies `lodash` and `microevent` duplicated in your `package.json` file.

Comment: This doesn't work with `react-dnd@2.3.0` and `react@15.3.1`. See [my answer in this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40499267/react-dnd-avoid-using-finddomnode#answer-43806453)