# How to refactor findDOMNode out

Tags: reactjs

I know findDOMNode is a no-no, I have a feeling that I can get rid of it.

I recently refactored my component to use a `Button` component instead of a `button` tag. It looks like this now:

```
<Button
   ref={(input) => this.toggleZipLink = input}>
   Add New Zip
</Button>
```

and I have a function in my component that gets called from another component via a prop:

```
shouldClickOutside(e) {
    if (findDOMNode(this.toggleZipLink).contains(e.target)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have to use findDOMNode because `this.toggleZipLink` is a component. If `Button` was a `button` I wouldn't need it.

Is there any way I can expose the inner `button` tag to it's parent? I notice that this.toggleZipLink has a refs object, but it seems to be empty. For reference, Button is *not* stateless function component, so it should support ref's.

**Solution Edit:**

Inside `Button` I added a ref `ref={(button) => this.button = button}`. Then in the parent div I can access it as via `this.toggleZipLink.button`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React DnD: Avoid using findDOMNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40499267/react-dnd-avoid-using-finddomnode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could expose some other non-ref prop on `Button` (named, say, `buttonRef`) to pass your ref callback through on. `Button`'s render then passes `this.props.buttonRef` as `ref` to the underlying `button`.

```
class Button extends Component {
  render() {
    const { buttonRef, ...passThroughProps } = this.props;
    return <button {...passThroughProps} ref={buttonRef} />
  }
}
```

Also, you could just take the ref onto `Button` and then access it via `toggleZipLink.whateverYouNamedYourRef`.

Passing through refs is hard and takes some boilerplate.