# getting warning on button click stick mode(findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode) issue in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am getting below warning on button click

**findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference. Learn more ab**

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-cartwright-v5zqy

```
<button
        onClick={() => {
          messageRef.current && messageRef.current.handleClick();
        }}
      >
```

HTML

**const messageRef = useRef();**

```
<MessageModal
        ref={messageRef}
        message={message.message}
        severity={message.severity}
      />
```

Comment: Looks like issue with `MuiAlert` from "@material-ui/lab/Alert".

Comment: Open an [issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/packages/material-ui-lab) and wait. Fork the repo, fix it and issue a pull request, and wait. Fork the repo, fix it and maintain a local copy.

Comment: @user944513 Seems on progress https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/pull/97

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React DnD: Avoid using findDOMNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40499267/react-dnd-avoid-using-finddomnode)